# Jquery and Wordpress : The image file never shows up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, wordpress

So I was trying to implement the cool  [sexy curl](https://github.com/elliottkember/the-sexy-curls-jquery-plugin) effect by Elliot Kember.
I got all the javascript inserted with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/turn.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/turn_fire.js'></script>
```

I have added the css file too.
Added the code image with

```
<img id="target" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/code.png"/>
```

But there is a line `$( '#target' ).fold({turnImage: 'fold.png'});` which needs the `fold.png` image file.
But even if I put the image in the folder it never shows up. Every other thing works almost fine. The code.png image shows up, it even gets resized and all. 
I have trying giving the full path too. But no results.The image never shows up.

Comment: Did you look at your server's logs to see if any requests for that image actually get to the server? JS may be using an incorrect URL and getting a 404 response.

Comment: i am on xampp on my local machine and i am pretty sure the image is there

Comment: "pretty sure" is not "sure". Check the logs. It doesn't matter WHERE you put the image if the actual code is requesting it from some completely different location. "I put the cars keys on the table by the door." is of no use when your significant other is digging around on top of the fridge.

Comment: use bloginfo instead of get_bloginfo if you're just going to echo

Comment: ::1 - - [14/Feb/2012:22:30:09 +0530] "GET /wordpress/http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/fold.png HTTP/1.1" 403 1092 "http://localhost/wordpress/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.77 Safari/535.7"

it is there in the access log

Comment: @AramKocharyan will do that from next time..i'm newbie to php and wordpress ..not sure about the difference

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also need to give the "directory" option to point to the path where you put the images. You can look that up in the source of the plugin: https://github.com/elliottkember/the-sexy-curls-jquery-plugin/blob/master/turn.js

If you don't set "directory" it will be set to "." and the path you give for the image will be relative to your current location.

Based on the log message you gave, directory has to be "/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/02"

Comment: That is it :) .. I was hunting for errors in turn_fire.js and it was there in turn.js. Thanks very much. Your bounty is due in 23 hours :)